# How to force a touch event to bubble?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, touch

Is there a way to force a touch event to bubble?  By default touch events on the ipad are not bubbling up.

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function (e) {
   closePopupOnClick(e, popup);
});
```

So one has to click again for this to fire.  Suggestions anyone?

Comment: As far as I know all events bubble up to Document object. Maybe what you want is `e.target`, which refers to the element that fires the event?